Walks on a circle
A walk on a circle is a sequence of oriented arcs of equal length on a circle starting and ending at the same point. The endpoint of an arc is always the starting point of the next arc of the walk. The circle is divided into \$m\$ segments. A round trip on the circle is only a walk if each segment is visited equally often.
By convention, we fix the start point to be the point corresponding to the number 3 on the face of a clock and the first step to start in the mathematically positive sense (counterclockwise).

In the plot, the arcs are on circles with different radii, but only drawn so for better readability.
The circle on the plot is divided into \$m=6\$ segments (with \$360/m = 60\$ degree angle) and shows \$30\$ arcs, \$3m = 18\$ orange arcs, and \$2m = 12\$ purple ones.
In general, a walk has \$m(n+1)\$ steps, of which \$m(k+1)\$ steps are positively and \$m(n-k)\$ steps are negatively oriented.
If you set L for the positive ('left') and R for the negative oriented ('right') arcs, the walk shown in the plot is described by
[L,L,L,L,R,L,L,R,L,L,R,L,R,R,L,L,L,L,L,R,R,L,L,L,R,R,R,R,L,R].

Challenge:
Implement a function that, given \$m\$, the number of segments, and \$l\$, the length of the walks, outputs a list of binary strings \$(1 \leftarrow L, 0 \leftarrow R)\$ representing the walks as defined above. Cases where no walks of the desired type exist can be ignored for the sake of simplicity.
The output is either a list of walks or the walks are printed line by line. The order of the walks is not prescribed.
The function should work for all \$m, l \ge 1\$. Tests should be executed for \$m=2,\, l=6\$, and \$m=3,\, l=9\$ to prove its functionality.
For \$m = 2\$ and \$l = 6\$, the output might look like:
110000
100100
100001
111100
111001
110110
110011
101101
100111
111111

Credits:
Further examples can be found on this page which is the source of the description, taken with permission of the author, who also has a reference implementation on GitHub.
This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.

Should we handle l mod m is not 0?

@l4m2 Can you please explain the context?

like m=3, l=7 ?

I'm old enough to have known and used this kind of walks on a circle ...

@Arnauld Haha, yes, indeed! And the theory of 'walks on a circle' is still successfully used by safe crackers today.

JavaScript (V8), 103 bytes
l=>g=(m,z='0',p=0)=>z[l-1]?print(z):[1,0].map(y=>{(f[p%=m]=-~f[p])+!p>l/m||g(m,z+y,p+y);--f[p];p+=m-1})

Try it online!

Nekomata, 19 bytes
2ᵚ~ᵖ{:∫PÄx--v%Ţ≡¿$L

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as l m.
2ᵚ~ᵖ{:∫PÄx--v%Ţ≡¿$L
2ᵚ~                     Find a tuple of [0,1] of length l
   ᵖ{                   Such that:
     :                      Duplicate
      ∫                     Cumulative sum
       P                    Check if all items are positive (so that the tuple starts with 1)
        Ä                   Multiply by 2
         x-                 Subtract [0,1,...,l-1]
           -                Subtract from the original tuple
            v%              Modulus m
              Ţ             Count the occurrences of each item
               ≡            Check if all counts are equal
                ¿$L         And check that there are m distinct items

Nekomata will output all valid solutions in the default mode.

@KevinCruijssen Thanks. Fixed.

Jelly, 24 bytes
IŻH_ƲÄ%ĠẈĠḢL⁼
Ø+ṗŒHḢçƇ»0

A dyadic Link that accepts a positive integer, the walk length, on the left and a positive integer, the segment count, on the right and yields a list of lists of 1s and 0s, the walks.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
IŻH_ƲÄ%ĠẈĠḢL⁼ - Link 1, Valid +/- Walk?: list of {1,-1}, Potential+/-Walk; #Segments
    Ʋ         - last four links as a monad - f(Potential+/-Walk):
I             -   forward differences
 Ż            -   prefix with a zero
  H           -   halve
   _          -   subtract {Potential+/-Walk}
                (replaces any change of direction with a zero)
                e.g. [1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1]
                 ->  [1,1,1, 0,-1,0, 0,0,1,1]
                (actually negates everything too, but that doesn't matter!)
     Ä        - cumulative sums
      %       - modulo {#Segments} -> VisitedSegmentIndices
       Ġ      - group indices by their values
        Ẉ     - length of each -> UnlabeledSegmentVisitCounts
         Ġ    - group indices by their values
          Ḣ   - head
           L  - length -> SomeVisitCountGroupSize
            ⁼ - equals {#Segments}
 
Ø+ṗŒHḢçƇ»0 - Link - Make Walks: positive integer, WalkLength; positive integer, #Segments
Ø+         - [1, -1]
  ṗ        - Cartesian power {WalkLength} -> all length WalkLength lists with alphabet [1, -1]
   ŒH      - split into two halves
     Ḣ     - head -> Potential+/-Walks (those lists that start with 1)
       Ƈ   - keep those Potential+/-Walks for which:
      ç    -   call Link 1 as a dyad - Valid +/-Walk?(Potential+/-Walk, #Segments)
        »0 - maximum with zero (replaces each -1 instruction with a zero)


R, 146 126 bytes
\(m,l){lapply(1:2^(l-1)-1,\(i){x=1-i%/%2^(l:1-1)%%2;if(all(sort((cumsum(2*x-1)-x)%%m)==rep(1:m-1,e=l/m)))cat(x,"\n",sep="")})}

Try it on rdrr.io!
Edits:

Thanks to @pajonk, made into an anonymous function
Replaced do.call(expand.grid,c(1,rep(list(0:1),l-1))) with iterating or indices 1:2^(l-1)-1, then converting to binary with 1-i%/%2^(l:1-1)%%2
replaced !any(diff(table(factor(...,0:(m-1)))))with all(sort(...)==rep(1:m-1,e=l/m))


134 bytes. You can omit f= and submit anonymous function (if you don't reference the name in the code, eg. in a recuscion).

Charcoal, 40 bytes
ＮθＮηΦＥ…Ｘ²⊖ηＸ²η⍘ι²⁼η×θ⌈Ｅθ№Ｅι﹪⁻Σ⁺×…ιξ²νξθλ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Brute force.
Ｎθ                                          Input `m` as a number
  Ｎη                                        Input `l` as a number
      …                                     Range from
        ²                                   Literal integer `2`
       Ｘ                                    Raised to power
          η                                 Input `l`
         ⊖                                  Decremented
            ²                               To literal integer `2`
           Ｘ                                Raised to power
             η                              Input `l`
     Ｅ                                      Map over values
               ι                            Current value
              ⍘                             Converted to base
                ²                           Literal integer `2`
    Φ                                       Filtered where
                       θ                    Input `m`
                      Ｅ                     Map over implicit range
                        №                   Count of
                                       λ    Inner value in
                          ι                 Outer value
                         Ｅ                  Map over digits
                                 ι          Outer value
                                …           Truncated to length
                                  ξ         Innermost index
                               ×            Repeated
                                   ²        Twice
                              ⁺             Concatenated with
                                    ν       Innermost digit
                             Σ              Digital sum
                            ⁻               Subtract
                                     ξ      Innermost index
                           ﹪                Modulo
                                      θ     Input `m`
                     ⌈                      Take the maximum
                   ×                        Multiplied by
                    θ                       Input `m`
                 ⁼                          Equals
                  η                         Input `l`
                                            Implicitly print


05AB1E, 25 24 bytes
oLb¹ùʒSDηO·-ā<+I%Ð¢ËiÙgQ

Inspired by @alephalpha's Nekomata's answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Inputs in the order \$l,m\$.
Try it online or verify both test cases.
Explanation:
o                        # Push 2 to the power the first (implicit) input `l`
 L                       # Pop and push a list in the range [1,2**l]
  b                      # Convert each inner value to a binary-string
   ¹ù                    # Only keep those of length `l`
     ʒ                   # Then filter it further by:
      S                  #  Convert the binary-string to a list of bits
       D                 #  Duplicate it
        ηO               #  Cumulative sum: prefixes and sum each prefix
          ·              #  Double each prefix-sum
           -             #  Subtract that from the list of binary-bits
            ā<+          #  Add the 0-based index to each
               I%        #  Modulo the second input `m`
                 Ð       #  Triplicate that
                  ¢      #  Pop two, and count each value
                   Ëi    #  If all counts are the same:
                     Ù   #   Uniquify the remaining copy
                      g  #   Pop and push its length
                       Q #   Check whether it equals the (implicit) second input `m`
                         # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)

